# Youtube android player api getCurrentTimeMillis only updates every 1 second

Tags: android, youtube-api

I'm using the Youtube player android api (latest version, fetched from https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/). In my app I've added a timer that calls the player's getCurrentTimeMillis method every 200 msec. The problem is that the method returns the same value for each second that passes by. for example, I get the following output after the running the app:

1877
 1877
 1877
 1877
 1877
 2878
 2878
 2878
 2878
 2878
 3879
 3879
 3879
 3879
 3879
 4880
 4880
 4880
 4880
 4880
 5881

As you can see, the time effectively updates every 1 second (5 timer ticks). The same happens with a timer delay of 100 msec (every 10 ticks).
This of course, does not happen with the javascript api or the AS3 api.

Does anyone have any idea why it happens and how can I get a higher resolution?

I tried the same app on the Nexus 7 and Galaxy Nexus (both running android 4.3) and got the same results.

Thanks in advance!
Roy

Comment: can you share some code?

Comment: Function `getCurrentTimeMillis` returns more accurate values after video fully loaded.
Probably you're testing it on video which still downloading while playing.

Comment: Hey,
Thanks for replaying...
I've made sure the video is loaded (VideoLoaded state change happened) before i started querying for the time.
I'm using the following code:
`
    Timer t = new Timer();
    TimerTask scanTask = new TimerTask() {
     @Override
           public void run() {
            timedFunction();
           }};


       t.schedule(scanTask, 0, 200); 
 private void timedFunction()
 {
  if (_player !=null && _player.isPlaying())
  {
   newTime = _player.getCurrentTimeMillis();
    Log.d("YoutubeTime",Integer.toString(newTime));
} `
@Emmanuel
@asktomsk

Comment: Hi, 
For now, i solved it using a stopwatch that keeps track of the time and  pieces of code that resets it when the playback state changes. 
Its not optimal, but i get accuracy of around 50ms from the real time (=the first getCurrentTimeMillis  response in any given second).

I still would love to know if this "bug" replicates on other android versions/ youtube versions / devices and if its a bug or just normal behavior for the android youtube player API (comparing to Iframe API and AS3).
Roy

Comment: Hey,
Anyone happened to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

hello i have same problem. and i could't solve this....

this is 4 years ago trouble. still nobody have answer.

so, I made the code to handle it the way I wanted.

it have still 200ms time error. but it is better than 1 second

```
boolean first = true;
currentVideoTime = Yplayer.getCurrentTimeMillis();
while (!quitThread)
{
    Thread.sleep(100);
    if(Yplayer.isPlaying())
    {
        if(currentVideoTime == Yplayer.getCurrentTimeMillis())
        {
            if(first)
            {
                startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                first = false;
            }
            timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
            updateTime = currentVideoTime+timeInMilliseconds;
       }
       else
       {
           updateTime = currentVideoTime = Yplayer.getCurrentTimeMillis();
           first = true;
       }
}
```

below is test timetable

---

[getCurrentTimeMillis][updateTime]

[0][152]

[0][289]

[0][429]

[0][565]

[691][715]

[691][691]

[691][691]

[691][831]

[691][971]

[691][1111]

[691][1251]

[1671][1392]

[1671][1671]

[1671][1671]

[1671][1816]

[1671][1949]

[1671][2082]

[1671][2228]

[1671][2363]

[2516][2512]

[2516][2516]

[2516][2516]

[2516][2658]

[2516][2796]

[2516][2938]

[3502][3073]

[3502][3502]

[3502][3502]

[3502][3641]

[3502][3782]

[3502][3921]

[3502][4053]

[4510][4158]

[4510][4510]

[4510][4510]

[4510][4650]

[4510][4791]

[4510][4931]

[4510][5070]

[4510][5212]

[5528][5346]

[5528][5528]

[5528][5528]

[5528][5693]

[5528][5860]

[5528][6001]

[6479][6164]

[6479][6479]